Узнать, запущена ли программа
os.system('ps -C ffmpeg')

Так получаем список в котором будет один процесс с именем 'ffmpeg'
Если выполнить команду с именем процесса которого не существует. Тоже выдаст список, но будет  пусты.
Как узнать, запущен ли процесс и выставить на него условие. То есть, если запущен, пропускаем условие и наоборот...

При запуске через os.system выводит в консоль, а вам нужно этот результат парсить - как я понимаю, ваш вопрос в этом. Вместо os.system можно использовать subprocess.check_output, выходную строку разбирать. А в целом, попробуйте psutil

Самое простое через библиотеку psutil

pip install psutil

import time
import psutil

def search_program():  
    while True:
        for process in psutil.process_iter():
            if process.name() == 'Taskmgr.exe':
                print("Диспетчер задач работает!")        
        time.sleep(1)
            
search_program()


Может проще через регулярку?  os.system('ps -C ffmpeg'), как проверить присутствует ли в строчке 'ffmpeg'?

А зачем городить велосипед? Две строчки кода: простые, понятные,  с удобным интерфейсом.. чем вас не устраивают?

Кода много, возможно через регулярку проще будет?

На мой вкус, проще некуда  всю необходимую работу берёт на себя библиотека, вам остаётся только сочинить оптимизированное условие.

import psutil
for process in psutil.process_iter():

Любопытно, возможно сразу импортировать в тот момент когда обращаемся, TYT.process_iter():
